# Not able to extract text format response in karate

Tags: karate

- def response = response.applicationId

response is in text/plain format:

applicationId=12345&text=000

i need to extract only application id use it next scenario request

Comment: @PeterThomas can you please check this and this is not duplicate questions

Comment: sorry it is a duplicate. else please assume that this is not supported by karate and you are welcome to contribute code, it is open-source